# Cant be compiled - Turbo Pascal

Tags: pascal

can someone say to me, where is error due to I cant compile the program? Thanks. This is error description:

```
Compiling main.pas
main.pas(4,1) Error: Illegal expression
main.pas(4,6) Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but "identifier A" found
Fatal: Compilation aborted
Error: /usr/bin/ppcx64 returned an error exitcode (normal if you did not specify a source file to be compiled)
```

Program source code:

````
    program Hello;
begin

type a = array [1..6] of integer;
integer a : array;

a[1]:=2;
a[2]:=6;
a[3]:=4;
a[4]:=2;
a[5]:=4;
a[6]:=3;

n:=6;

x:=a[1];

for i:=2 to 6 do
begin
{
  if (a[i-1]>=x) then
  begin
  a[i]:=a[i] - x div 2;
  end;
  else 
  begin
  a[i]:=a[i] + x;
  x:= x + mod x(a[i] + 1);
  end;
}
end;


  writeln (a[i]);
end.

    ```
````

Answer (score 4):

Compiler is complaining about unexpected token.

First problem is that keyword `begin` is misplaced (as Loren Pechtel pointed out) and compiler treats your type definition and variables declaration as code. `begin` should be where your program logic starts. See [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/pascal_program_structure.htm) tutorial to understand TurboPascal program structure.

Another problem is in definition of array type. First you need to create type and name it using identifier (`hexad` in my example below). That identifier then becomes a type name such as `integer` so you can use it for further `var` declarations. [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/pascal_arrays.htm) is another tutorial on TurboPascal array types.

```
type
   hexad = array [1..6] of integer;
```

and then you can declare a variable of that type (`hexad` in my case):

```
var
   a: hexad;
```

Note that you can have more types defined under keyword `type` and more variables under keyword `var` so it is a good practice to keep them on separate line and indent type definitions and variable declarations.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the declaration problem that blami pointed out you have the begin in the wrong place--your definitions are being treated as code, not variables.

Don't put too much faith in the compiler's error messages, it often says things that aren't related to the error at all.  It's very good about pointing to **where** the error is, though (other than when you failed to close something, then the where can be crazy.)